# How to negate: not a limit point (symbolic logic)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, logic, first-order-logic

1.**There are few I have seen here**.

$\forall N(x), \exists x'\in B, (x'\neq x\wedge x'\in E)$.

$\forall N(x), \exists x'\in B, (x'\neq x\to x\not\in E)$.

$\forall r>0, \exists x'\in N_r(x)\cap E, x'\neq x$

$\forall r>0, d(x',x)<r$

...etc?

(can't make it a full sentence for the last one using distance)

**How should I negate these statements?**

2.**What about an interior point?** (how to negate)

$\exists r>0, x'\in N_r(x)\to x'\in E$

3.Finally, **how should I use these to prove that $E$ is open iff $E^c$ is closed?** (Rudin 2.33)

Suppose $E^c$ is closed

Proof:

Choose $x\in{E}$, so $x\not\in{E^c}$

{By the contrapositive of the definition of a closed set:

$x\in{E^c}'\to x\in E^c$ (by definition)

$x\not\in{E^c}\to x\not\in{E^c}'$ (by contrapositive)
}

$x\not\in{E^c}'$

$x\in\{??\}$ **negation of limit point**

....

Answer (score 2):

A point $x$ is a limit point of $E$, whenever for every neighbourhood $O$ of $x$, there is some $x' \in E$, such that $x \neq x'$ and $x' \in O$.

So in a first order formula, assuming we have the notation $\mathcal{N}(x)$ for the set of all (or just the open) neighbourhoods of $x$:

$$x \in E' \text{ iff } \forall O \in \mathcal{N}(x): \exists x' \in E: (\lnot(x = x') \land x' \in O)$$

The negation of this  using standard logical rules would be

$$ x \notin E' \text{ iff } \exists O \in \mathcal{N}(x): \forall x' \in E: x = x' \lor x' \notin O$$

And the last part can be seen to be equivalent to $E \setminus \{x\} \subseteq X \setminus O$ or $O \cap (E \setminus \{x\}) = \emptyset$.

So $$ x \notin E' \text{ iff } \exists O \in \mathcal{N}(x): O \cap (E \setminus \{x\}) = \emptyset$$

A point $x$ is an interior point of $E$ iff $\exists O \in \mathcal{N}(x): O \subseteq E$, so it's not iff $\forall O \in \mathcal{N}(x): O \nsubseteq E$, and the latter means that this $O$ intersects $X \setminus E$ (some point in $O$ is not in $E$, which is exactly such an intersection point).

So $$x \notin \operatorname{Int}(E) \text{ iff } \forall O \in \mathcal{N}(x): O \cap (X \setminus E) \neq \emptyset $$

To see that $E$ is open iff $X \setminus E$ is closed, these formulae are not too much of a help. Just reasoning will do it: suppose $E$ is open. To see that $F = X \setminus E$ is closed, we need to prove $F' \subseteq F$. So suppose $x \in F'$, and $x \notin F$, so $x \in E$. As $E$ is open and contains $x$ it is a neighbourhood of $x$ that howver misses $F$ entirely while $x \notin F$. This would mean that $x \notin F'$ (you could use the formulae above to see this), contradiction. So such an $x$ cannot exist and $X \setminus E$ is closed.

The other direction is quite similar as well.

Comment: Sorry but does mean the symbol ":" above in your reply?

Comment: @ZFR standard logic: such that, a separator between a quantor and a formula.

Answer (score 0):

To negate the given statements, *first* apply the rule of dual negation of the quantifiers, repeating as needed until the negation sign is "moved" to the predicate, and *then* negate the predicate, using DeMorgan's rules if required.

The negation of "every $x$ in $A$ is $P(x)$" is "some $x$ in $A$ is not $P(x)$"
$$\neg\Big(\forall x \in A, P(x)\Big) \; \iff \; \exists x\in A, \neg P(x)$$

And vice versa:
$$\neg\Big(\exists x \in A, P(x)\Big) \; \iff \; \forall x\in A, \neg P(x)$$

**Note:** We do *not* negate the restriction on the domain of discourse.

So, for example:
$$\begin{align}
\neg \forall x \in A, \exists y\in B, \big(y=f(x) \vee x=f(y)\big)
\; \iff \; & \exists x\in A, \neg \exists y\in B, \big(y=f(x) \vee x=f(y)\big) 
\\ \iff \; & \exists x\in A,\forall y\in B, \neg \big(y=f(x) \vee x=f(y)\big)
\\ \iff \; & \exists x\in A,\forall y\in B, \big(y\neq f(x) \wedge x\neq f(x)\big)
\end{align}$$

---

Also $\neg (A\to B) \;\iff\; (A\wedge \neg B)$

Can you do the first and second problems now?

---

For the third problem, *hint:* a set is closed if it contains all of its limits points, and a set is open if it contains none of them.  So show that all the limit points of a set are limit points of the complement and *vice versa*.

Comment: Wrong terminology here. "Domain of discourse" refers to the entire discourse and has nothing to do with the set over which a variable is quantified. But correct method.